# Laying out Universal Apps in XCode 4

Tags: ios, xcode4, universal

I'm trying to do the basics steps of creating a universal (iphone/ipad) app in Xcode 4. I don't want to be using INterface Builder, if possible, and I want to get away from the cumbersome if statements:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
```

I create a "window-based project" to get the Universal template that Apple provides. This gives me the three app delegates, with the iPhone and iPad having their own XIBs, inside their specific folders.

I would now like to add a view controller, so I create a master "MasterViewController", and two subclassed versions "MasterViewController_iPhone" and "MasterViewController_iPad". I do not create XIBs with any of these. (Do I need to?)

Here is where I get confused. In the master app delegate, I place the code

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I don't add any other code, allowing the sub-classed app delegates to instantiate their respective view controllers. For example, in the iphone app delegate I place:

```
myVC_iPhone = [[MasterViewController_iPhone alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; 
[self.window addSubview: myVC_iPhone];
```

But this gives me the error:

```
Incompatible pointer types sending 'MasterViewController_iPhone *' to parameter of type 'UIView *'
```

I'm missing something basic here. Perhaps my naming conventions are wrong; perhaps makeKeyAndVisible shouldn't be in the master app delegate; perhaps I need XIBs for each view controller. Can anyone push me along here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addSubview:` takes an UIView as parameter not the view controller surrounding it. You should be fine using `[self.window addSubview: myVC_iPhone.view];`.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding your view controller as the `rootViewController`

```
self.window.rootViewController = myVC_iPhone;
```